# args4J doesn't work with gradle

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle

I'm totally new to gradle so it may be a obvious problem:

I'm using eclipse with gradle and I actually have no problem adding dependencies for junit or stuff, it adds the junit lib to the gradle dependencies and there's no problem using junit, but if i try to use args4j (also with adding the dependency) it just doesn't work.

Just to make sure there's no problem with the build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
version = '1.0'
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'title', 
        'Implementation-Version': version,
        'Main-Class':'path.to.main.Main'
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

test {
    systemProperties 'property': 'value'
}

dependencies{
    compile 'args4j:args4j-site:2.0.25'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.+'
}
```

and No I'm not using title or path.to.main ^^

Eclipse shows me that the import (args4j) cannot be resolved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot main "args4j" module:

```
compile group: 'args4j',             name: 'args4j',        version: '2.0.25'
compile group: 'args4j',             name: 'args4j-site',   version: '2.0.25'
```

Comment: Oh man... thank you, it finally works :D
i tried it the same way but had for name args4j-site ^^

Comment: Ok i just noticed that http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/args4j/args4j-site/2.0.25 doesn't work this way ^^ if i remove  "-site" it works but thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

With gradle-7.1 this works for me:

```
// build.gradle

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation group: 'args4j',    name: 'args4j',         version: '2.33'
    implementation group: 'args4j',    name: 'args4j-site',    version: '2.33'
}
```